# Unable to tun TCGAbiolinks

Tags: r, linux, installation, rstudio, blob

I have installed TCGAbiolinks using anaconda.
When I try to start it from Rstudio by `library(TCGAbiolinks)` the following error pops up:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TCGAbiolinks’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘blob’ 1.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.2.0 is required
```

I have tried to update `blob` or install the requested version manually, but then I get the error:

```
package ‘blob=1.2.0’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

(I have also tried downgrading R to an older version (3.6.0), but the problem persisted with the additional warning that `TCGAbiolinks` was made for 3.6.1)

Attempts to install the developers version of `TGCAbiolinks` resulted in different errors.

Help would be much appreciated! I am very new to command line usage and unix in general and am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing on RStudio with BiocManager.

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("TCGAbiolinks")

library(TCGAbiolinks)

Comment: I had installed it that way. Fortunately I found a solution (see below). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Updating all packages in RStudio and restarting did the trick!